# Running a python script via crontab does not accept parameters containing %

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a python script that accepts custom parameters via sys and getopt modules.
The cron job looks like:

```
* * * * * /HS/py/py_venv/venv/bin/python /HS/py/py_venv/src/SP/yh_scrape_product_info.py -c TSX.AP% -vpn False
```

I have narrowed down this problem to the first argument TSX.AP%.

This is a parameter that I take to execute a DB query.

If I add the wildcard % inside my script, therefore only passing TSX.AP to cron, the crojob works. This also works if i paste the command directly inside the terminal like this:

```
/HS/py/py_venv/venv/bin/python /HS/py/py_venv/src/SP/yh_scrape_product_info.py -c TSX.AP% -vpn False
```

Now I am thinking to add another argument to specify wether the wildcard needs to be added or not, but I would like to understand if there is a better solution and also this problem made me lose almost the whole day troubleshooting I really want to understand what it happening!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man 5 crontab`:

```
   The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to  be
   run.   The  entire  command  portion  of the line, up to a newline or %
   character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the
   SHELL  variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command,
   unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline charac‐
   ters,  and  all  data  after the first % will be sent to the command as
   standard input. There is no way to split a  single  command  line  onto
   multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "\".
```

In particular:  **Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\),**

A simple work-around would be to put `/HS/py/py_venv/venv/bin/python /HS/py/py_venv/src/SP/yh_scrape_product_info.py -c TSX.AP% -vpn False` in a bash script and run **that** from cron.

Comment: Hi Tink thank you for pointing this out, I want to be able to pass the % sign so that I can enter a finite search therm for the SQL query or search with the wildcard. I thought weird noone ever bumped into this problem yet! I am going to try escaping it, even if it doesnt look too elegant

Comment: I'm pleased to hear =}